# Simply trying to access a field of an object from an Array and I can't manage it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the elementary question, but I just cannot get this most trivial thing working.   Does anyone have
I recreated this in jsfiddle and it works there, but not in my environment.  This is an exactly copy from my code.  In my environment it always returns undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/JNsaC/

```
function Card (first , last , mid) {
    this.first = first ;
    this.last = last ;
    this.mid = mid ;

}

var testArray = [ new Card("A", "B", "C"), new Card("D", "E", "E") ]

alert(testArray[1].mid);
```

Thanks,
Dale

Here's the answer.  Thanks for the help
[I cannot access fields in my object directly or with a getter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162762/i-cannot-access-fields-in-my-object-directly-or-with-a-getter-function)

Comment: "I recreated this in jsfiddle and it works there, but not in my environment". Must be something in your environment then. What environment is that?

Comment: Please ignore the 'cost' typo.  That's not the issue.  I just forgot to resave jsfiddle after I fixed that typo.    My environment is Eclipse, but It's only one html file and one js file.

Comment: Could you post your whole html + js files here? They should be quite small I guess. Are you *viewing* the page in Eclipse or merely developing it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

When I run your jsfiddle, I get undefined. The code in it is :

```
function Card (first , last , mid) {
    this.first = first ;
    this.last = last ;
    this.mid = mid ;

}

var testArray = [ new Card("A", "B", "C"), new Card("D", "E", "E") ]

alert(testArray[1].cost);
```

which is different than what you posted here. Replacing `alert(testArray[1].cost);` by `alert(testArray[1].mid);` works for me. Maybe it's just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle link uses 'cost' instead of 'mid', which is why it returns 'undefined'.

I don't see any problems with the code you pasted though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your jsFiddle.  You are referencing `.cost` instead of `.mid`.  If you change it to `.mid`, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JNsaC/2/.