# I cannot access fields in my object directly or with a getter function

Tags: javascript

I've been banging my head against the wall on this trivial problem for hours.
I'm simply trying to do what the code below shows and it doesn't work for me.  It works fine in JSFiddle, but not in my environment.  If you read this post earlier, I'm reposting because I'm desperate and everyone caught the typo that wasn't really the problem.  Oops on my part.
If I define a toString method, that works for some reason.  If I define a getMid() function, that doesn't work.  If I use toString as a hacky getMid() function it works.  I'm confused as heck.
Could my doctype or any other html/js headings be affecting it?  I'm just using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.
This fails for me in all browsers and I've tried it on another computer.  Thanks for helping me solve this mystery.

```
function Card (first , last , mid) {
    this.first = first ;
    this.last = last ;
    this.mid = mid ;

}

var testArray = [ new Card("A", "B", "C"), new Card("D", "E", "E") ];

alert(testArray[1].mid);
```

Thanks again, Dale

Edited to add the "optional" semicolon after testArray assignment.

I'm expecting anything but undefined.  I think I've narrowed it down.  testArray is being build like so:

```
alert(availableCardsForSet[0].cost);
for (var int = 0; int < 10 && testArray.length < 10; int++) {
testArray.push(availableCardsForSet.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*availableCardsForSet.length),1));
}
alert(testArray[0].cost);
alert(testArray[0].toString());
```

The first alert gives me a valid result.  The second alert gives me undefined.  Strangely  finalSet[0].toString gives me a valid result.  So I think it may be down to, how am I breaking this thing in my for loop.   I get the following error/warning when I run it through JSLint   Problem at "line 15 character 14: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined"  Line 15 is the guts of the for loop.   I appreciate all of the responses.  Hopefully this new info will help.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the `var testArray...` line

Comment: It surprisingly works with or without that..... in jsfiddle that is.  in my code, I have the semicolon.

Comment: @grc: Semicolons are mostly optional in JavaScript.

Comment: I know browsers let you leave them out sometimes, but it could be a problem in a strict environment.

Comment: Can you say in what your environment you are having this problem?

Comment: What is the exact error?  Does Firebug say anything? this works for me in all cases..

Comment: What is the output you expect?? B or E

Comment: Could you either give us a link to the page or post the bits of code that work and don't work

Comment: @marcioAlmada 'E' is the expected output (and what you get from jsfiddle)

Comment: I get 'E' here... using Opera and Chrome

Comment: I added some useful newfound information to the question.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splice function returns an array containing the removed elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. [(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

---

This means that this code adds an *array containing the object* to testArray, rather than just adding *the object*:

```
testArray.push(availableCardsForSet.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*availableCardsForSet.length),1));
```

---

It can easily be fixed using `[0]`

```
testArray.push(availableCardsForSet.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*availableCardsForSet.length),1)[0]);
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/8Auvm/

Comment: Thanks!  I'm annoyed I didn't figure that out earlier.  Can you recommend a better/faster way of doing what I'm trying to do: randomly selecting/removing an item from an array.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with below doctype it is working for me,

browsers tested: IE8,Firefox3

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

function Card (first , last , mid) { 
    this.first = first ;
    this.last = last ;
    this.mid = mid ;
    }
var testArray = [ new Card("A", "B", "C"), new Card("D", "E", "F") ];
alert(testArray[1].mid);